# Functions to simulate random variables in scipy

Tags: scipy

I have been looking for what are the functions in scipy to simmulate a generic random variables. I just found the function scipy.stats.rv_discrete, but I do not know if there are another functions.

And another question is: What are the functions in scipy that generate random variables and use preprocesses?

I am very new programing with scipy, if anyone could help me I really appreciate it. Any advice is welcoming.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic random variables". In particular, what is "generic" here?

Comment: And what do you mean by preprocesses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.